# file_get_contents timing out for specific site?

Tags: php, html, timeout, screen-scraping, file-get-contents

Until recently I've had an automated script running which goes against Gamestop.com to gather game names/prices and such.

As of last week however, using file_get_contents appears to time out (it goes much longer than necessary then returns false). At first I thought they may have been blocking my server's IP, but on checking it out on my local dev machine, I get the same result.

So, my question is, is there any way to verify what is actually happening that is causing the function to return false? I have a sneaking suspicion that they may be blocking requests w/ the header that shows up with file_get_contents, could this be possible?

If anyone wants to also try the code locally for a sanity check, here is a very simple test:

```
<?php
     $test = file_get_contents("http://www.gamestop.com")
     echo $test;
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: use CUrl library to fetch data instead of file_get_contents, then you will be able to track some errors or emulate real browser

Comment: Bit of a typo by the way. `$test = file_get_contents("http://www.gamestop.com")` missing semi-colon ;-)

Comment: Have you configured allow_url_fopen in your PHP environment?

Comment: @Fred - yeah that was actually just an extra backspace when I copied and pasted. Had some extra commented out code to the right of it.

Comment: @Marc - yes. The code was actually functional for 1+ year, so I'm almost 100% sure the problem is something they've changed on their server at Gamestop.

Comment: @David Yep, that's the case alright. Even when using `cURL`, it won't show content.

Comment: @Fred - I'd imagine I could manually adjust the headers so that it does not show up as PHP though right? In theory, you could build a request using cURL that looks identical to a browser request?

Comment: @David I for one don't know how to do it, am not that well-versed enough with CURL. You could try it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was in fact Gamestop blocking the script by user agent, for whatever reason....

Solution was to set the user-agent to a browser, then everything works normally.